# Can't Focused Textbox JQuery

Tags: jquery, autofocus

i don't get any error message in my console, but `.focus()` function in JQuery isn't work.
i'm used 2 function that is `.focus` and `.val('')`... `.val('')` is working fine, but `.focus()` isn't work

here's my HTML code :

```js
    $('.sukses').show(function(){
       var notif = 'some message'; 
       $('.notif').html(notif);
    });    
    $('#kode').focus();
    $('.kode_guru').val('');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alert alert-success sukses" style="display: none">
        <strong>Success!</strong><p class="notif"></p>
    </div>

    <form action="#" id="form" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
       <input onblur="this.focus()" type="text" name="guru" id="kode" class="kode_guru">
    </form>
```

my program flow is, when something change in my textfield ('.kode_guru'), the notif will come out and text field will reset to '' and automaticly focused again for another input

hope you guys understand what i'm talking about
thanks

Comment: Seriously?! @Vikrant

Comment: @Vikrant - it is not work :(

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are talking about something like this:

```
$('.kode_guru').on('change', function() {
  $('.sukses').show(function() {
    var notif = 'some message';
    $('.notif').html(notif);
  });
  $('#kode').focus();
  $('.kode_guru').val('');
});
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rh5my5f0/1/)